# Delete mth element from an array

Tags: arrays

Given an array of size n, I need to a write a function which deletes every mth element in the array till only one element exists in the array and return that value.
Can somebody just give me the hints?

Comment: If this is homework samir, please tag it as such.

Comment: This is not homework...i have interview at Amazon so i m  preparing for it. Language does not matter..i just wanted the pseudo code

Comment: If m>2, you will always have m-1 elements left after the last iteration, won't you?  Unless you are talking about deleting every element with index x*m, where x=[0,inf)

Comment: If you can't do this yourself and they ask you about it, you're probably not cut out to do whatever they want you to do.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to solve the [Josephus Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem):

> There are people standing in a circle
>   waiting to be executed. After the
>   first man is executed, certain number
>   of people are skipped and one man is
>   executed. Then again, people are
>   skipped and a man is executed. The
>   elimination proceeds around the circle
>   (which is becoming smaller and smaller
>   as the executed people are removed),
>   until only the last man remains, who
>   is given freedom.
>
> The task is to choose the place in the
>   initial circle so that you survive
>   (are the last one remaining).

The wiki article includes a very simple recursive solution to the problem above: let n = number of people, k = people to skip per deletion, then:

```
f(1, k) = 0
f(n, k) = (f(n - 1, k) + k) % n
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account that the first person in the line is executed. It skips the first k people. Though it is possibly this way the OP wants to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The naive way to do it:

- Start a pointer at element **m**, delete it (by delete I mean put a marker there, since you don't want to have to reconstruct a new array every time you delete something)
- Increment your pointer **m** times.  If you are pointing to a deleted element, decrease your counter by 1, so you move past **m** non-deleted items.  Make sure to move back to position 0 if you go off the end of the array.
- Keep track of the number of items you have deleted.  Stop after **n-1**.

Comment: The non-naive way of doing it is to use a circularly-linked list instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

In python, which actually reconstructs the list for each run instead of deleting items. Could probably be done better.

This takes into account that the first (0th) item should be the first to go.

```
def lms(l, m, r=0):
    """Return last man standing in the lineup l where every mth man is
    executed."""
    if len(l) == 1: return l[0]
    return lms(
        [l[x] for x in range(len(l)) if (r + x) % m], # new list without exec.
        m,                                            # frequency
        (r + len(l)) % m)                             # remainder from this round

def get_lms(n, m):
    """Just a setup function, which creates a plain range list to serve to the function. 
    Any list of any items can be used."""
    l = [x for x in range(n)]
    return lms(l, m)

>>> get_lms(10, 3):
3
```

Comment: Where does the OP say that the first element is always deleted?

Comment: @Juliet - Nowhere. But he doesn't say that it shouldn't be either. I'm just providing an alternative that does.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement..bt seems to have high complexity

```
public static void DeleteM(int[] arr, int m)

    {
        int k = m;
        int count = 0;
        while (count<arr.Length-1)
        {
            if (m < arr.Length && arr[m]!=-1)
            {
                    arr[m] = -1; //Mark it
                    count++;//Set the marked count
                    m = m + k;
            }
            else
            {
                int i = 0;
                if (arr[i] == -1)
                {
                    while (arr[i] == -1 && i < arr.Length)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                m = i;

            }

        }
        for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
            if (arr[i] != -1) Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n,k=map(int,raw_input().split())
ans=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    ans=(ans+k)%i
print ans+1
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956957/6521116).

hope it helps.

```
function removeAtNth($array, $nth)
{
    $step = $nth - 1;       //gaps between operations
    $benchmark = 0;    
    while(isset($array[1]))
    {   
        $benchmark += $step;
        $benchmark = $benchmark > count($array) -1 ? $benchmark % count($array) : $benchmark;
        unset($array[$benchmark]);
        $array = array_values($array);
        echo implode('', $array)."\n";
    }   
}
```

test:

```
$array = [1,2, 3,4,5,6,7,8];
removeAtNth($array, 3);
```

result:

```
kris-roofe@krisroofe-Rev-station:~$ php test.php
1245678
124578
24578
2478
478
47
7
```