# Getting Time Limit Exceeded for linked list implementation of SPOJ : CLSLDR

Tags: doubly-linked-list

I have been trying to implement this question using circular doubly linked list. http://www.spoj.com/problems/CLSLDR/

I am getting Time Limit Exceeded for my code. Can someone please point out the mistake that I am doing ?

I have used an O(n) algorithm for identifying the last element after deleting every p-th element.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};


void deleteNode( struct Node* ptr ) {

    ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
    ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
    delete ptr;
}

int main() {

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );

    int t, n, m, p, i;
    cin >> t;
    while( t-- ) {
        cin >> n >> m >> p;
        struct Node* root = new Node;
        root->data = 1;
        struct Node* head = root;
        struct Node* nxt = NULL;

        for( i = 1;i < n;i++ ) {
            head->next = new Node;
            head->next->data = i + 1;
            head->next->prev = head;
            head = head->next;  
        }

        head->next = root;
        root->prev = head;

        head = root;

        for( i = 1;i < m;i++ ) {
            head = head->next;  
        }

        i = 1;
        while( n != 1 ) {

            for( ;i <= p;i++ ) {
                head = head->next;
            }
            nxt = head->next;
            deleteNode( head );
            head = nxt;
            i = 2;
            n--;        
        }

        cout << head->data << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855357/158037 if list based solution is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I guess O(n) approach is bound to TLE for the given constraints. Your approach will take T * n(10^6 * 10^3) which is 10^9 operations. 0.699s is the limit and even 1s would not be enough for that.