# How to remove every third element in a php array until only one element remains and print that element?

Tags: php, arrays

The array is like this

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

After that in each iteration the 3rd element should be removed until it reaches to a single element

the iteration will be something like this

index:0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

value:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
this is the normal one

index:0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

value:1 2 4 5 7 8
here 3 and 6 removed as they came out as the 3rd elements

then after 6 is removed it should count 7 and 8 as 1st and 2nd and go to value 1 which makes 1 as the 3rd element.This continues until there is only one element remaining.

output

```
12345678

1245678

124578

24578

2478

478

47

7
```

7 is the remaining element

Comment: you change your algorithm in middle of your sample .... you remove 3rd until you rich to `2478` in this place you remove first element... can you explain more???

Comment: at 2478 it was up to the 7, so counts 782 and removes 2

Comment: Exactly...at 2478 since 5 has been removed last it takes 7 as 1 and 8 as 2 and next it goes for starting i.e 2 which is the 3rd and it removes 2

Comment: What you've asked for *("...in each iteration the 3rd element should be removed until it reaches to a single element")* is not what you are trying to achieve. And to be honest, I'm not sure there is a pattern in what you are trying to achieve. It seems like you're arbitrarily selecting digits to remove after a while.

Comment: TunaMaxx- I exactly thought of the same thing when i first heard it.But imagine like this the array is not stopping at its maximum its going again to the a[0] till one element remains. 123456 think its the array... after taking 3 and 6 as i mentioned above it goes for 1.like its looping inside itself.

Comment: better perhaps "the 3rd element starting from where you left off."

Comment: Oh, it's rolling over. I get it. Ok, give me a few minutes. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Will `$a` always be 8 elements?

Comment: $a will be what we are defining...it can also be 8 or any other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code, hope it helps.

```
<?php
$array = [1,2, 3,4,5,6,7,8];

function removeAtNth($array, $nth)
{
    $step = $nth - 1;       //gaps between operations
    $benchmark = 0;    
    while(isset($array[1]))
    {   
        $benchmark += $step;
        $benchmark = $benchmark > count($array) -1 ? $benchmark % count($array) : $benchmark;
        echo $benchmark."\n";
        unset($array[$benchmark]);
        $array = array_values($array);
        echo implode('', $array)."\n";
    }   
}

removeAtNth($array, 3);
```

result:

```
kris-roofe@krisroofe-Rev-station:~$ php test.php
1245678
124578
24578
2478
478
47
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$thirds = array_chunk($a, 3);
```

$thirds now is like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
        )   
)
```

Then just loop through the $thirds array and [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to grab the last value.

However, I'm not sure why you're looking to get 7 at the end and not 8. Can you explain?

Comment: at 2478 ...2 rules out and gets 478.since 2 is the last removed number it takes 4 as 1,7 as 2 and 8 as 3 so 8 gets removed...remaining 47...since 8 is last removed 4 will be 1 7 will be 2 again it goes for 4 as 3 and 4 gets removed and 7 only remains